# Access VBA determining a Unique Value?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to write an If statement that determines if my column [Pack_Number] has only one Unique number or if there is more than one.

I'm not exactly sure of the syntax to make this check for an Access Table since it uses records instead of rows like Excel.

This isn't right but it shows what I'm trying to do:

```
If [Forms]![ReviewButton]![RetailEntry].[Form]![Pack_Number].Value = Distinct Then
MsgBox "It's Unique!"
Else
MsgBox "It's NOT Unique!"
End If
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this check or have an example they can show me?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider domain aggregate, [`DCount`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dcount-function-f6b5d78b-ad0b-4e42-be7a-11a64acbf3d3), to search on specific value. Below assumes form value is a string to encloses single quotes.

```vb
If DCount("Pack_Number", "myTable", _ "Pack_Number = '" & _
          [Forms]![ReviewButton]![RetailEntry].[Form]![Pack_Number].Value & "'") = 1 Then
  ...
```

Per @Erik's comment, no need to concatenate or punctuate:

```vb
If DCount("Pack_Number", "myTable", _
          "Pack_Number = [Forms]![ReviewButton]![RetailEntry].[Form]![Pack_Number].Value") = 1 Then
  ...
```

Comment: Note that there's no need for the string concatenation and quotes there, `DCount` supports form-based parameters: `DCount("Pack_Number", "myTable", "Pack_Number =  [Forms]![ReviewButton]![RetailEntry].[Form]![Pack_Number].Value")`. That handles both nulls and strings with quotes properly.